# Невозможно закрыть процесс с Delphi

Tags: winapi, windows, delphi

Есть такой код:

```
ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,Msg.WParam);
while ProcessHandle > 0 do
begin
  CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,Msg.WParam);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Хендл процесса есть, но функция `CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);` не убивает процес, и этот код зависает.

Как можно убить безвозвратно?

Answer (score 4):

Раз уж стоит тег `winapi`...

`::CloseHandle( ProcessHandle )` не прекращает процесс. Об этом написано в описании функции: [::CloseHandle на MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx)

Там же есть ссылка на статью [Terminating a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx), в которой описывается, как завершается процесс.

Есть, например, такая функция: `::TerminateProcess( HANDLE process, UINT exitCode )` ([TerminateProcess на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx)). Обратите внимание, эта функция асинхронная. Она только запускает "убивание" процесса и тут же возвращает значение. Если Вам необходимо дождаться того момента, когда процесс "убит" окончательно, используйте `::WaitForSingleObject` ([WaitForSingleObject - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)).
Также, заметьте, чтобы иметь право убить процесс, нужно создавать его с правами `PROCESS_TERMINATE` (хотя Вы  уже включили этот флаг в `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`).

Итого, Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
ProcessHandle := OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, Msg.WParam );
while ProcessHandle > 0 do
begin
    if( not TerminateProcess( ProcessHandle, 1 ) ) break;
    CloseHandle( ProcessHandle );
    ProcessHandle := OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, Msg.WParam );
    Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Ну и до кучи еще одна полезная ссылка [Как "начисто" завершить приложение в Win32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893)